# Although GOPATH is set, echo $GOPATH returns nothing

Tags: go

I have this weird issue.

When I run `go env`, I get the following:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/ethanc/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/ethanc/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/home/ethanc/marketstore/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build154822748=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

But when, I run `echo $GOPATH`, I get an empty new line. This happens for all other GO environment values as well when I try to echo them out:
[image: Empty GOPATH result]

This doesn't make sense because when I try to print out other path variables like `echo $HOME`, I get the correct value:

```
/home/ethanc
```

Does anyone have any idea why when I echo my `GOPATH`, only a new line is returned?

Comment: Compare the results of running “env” from the command-line, with what you are getting when you run it under the go compiler.  Likely go is setting those variables as part of starting “go”, and they don’t exist once that instance of go exits.

Comment: @DonSimon. You were right. Thank you!

Comment: They're defaults.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the [default value](https://rakyll.org/default-gopath/) for GOPATH.

Since it's never set, go will use it's reasonable default.

Main consquence of course is all your go projects sharing this $GOPATH.

---

**UPDATE**:

For the ones starting to learn go in 2023 or later, `$GOPATH` is deprecated. learn about [go modules](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules) instead.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you @DonSimon (https://stackoverflow.com/users/10453847/don-simon) for pointing me in the right direction.

So, while my go environment variables were set up correctly and `go env` returned the correct env. variables, it wasn't set in my bash shell.

I just followed the instructions of setting the GOPATH automatically in my terminal: [enter link description here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH#bash)

Specifically, I did this since I don't have `.bash_profile`:

1. `vi ~/.bashrc`
2. Added the following line of code at the bottom of the code: `export GOPATH=$HOME/go`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can  add the GOPATH in `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`

- When you start bash as an interactive shell (i.e., not to run a script), it reads `~/.bashrc`
- When invoked as a login shell, then it
  only reads `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`.
  To understand more
  difference between shells, read this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980)

Attaching what I have in my ~/.profile here

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin
```